# jquerymobile - pagecontainer doesnt fire consistently

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I have two html pages (jquerymobile ver 1.4.5)

## index.html

```
            $.when( $.ajax({
                    url: '/login', 
                    data: {username:u, password:p},
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json' 
                })
            ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                if(data.status == SUCCESS) {
                    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "home.html"); //<-- this doesnt work always. 
                } else {
                    showMessage(data.message, 'error');
                }
            });
```

the $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer code doesnt work consistently. When I run this in phonegap build, it shows

```
[phonegap] 200 /home.html
[phonegap] 200 /img/logo.png
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/autoreload
```

but the page on screen is still showing the index.html

When it reloads home.html, I have a logout button. When the user clicks that, I have same problem redirecting it back to index.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically Load is to 
Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
Sometimes it may not load data from local.
You can use 'change' instead of 'load' as follows,
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "test.html", { transition: "slide"
 } );

Comment: I understood the difference between load and change. But as stated in the question, phonegap is fetching the home.html (as seen from the CLI), but its not reflected in the UI. It is still stuck on the index.html page.